# Calculate CPU Utilization

Tags: operating-system, cpu-usage

i have an task to calculate CPU utilization, I have 4 proccess

P1 wait for I/O 30% of his time.

P2 wait for I/O 40% of his time.

P3 wait for I/0 20% of his time.

P4 wait for I/0 50% of his time.

my result is 0.99999993...it seems to me unreasonable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The probability that all processes are waiting for I/O (and therefore the CPU is idle) is:

```
0.3 * 0.4 * 0.2 * 0.5 = 0.012
```

The CPU is therefore busy with a probability of: `(1 - 0.012) = 0.988`, i.e. CPU utilization = `98.8%`.

Comment: I dont need to take the result with power 4? namely, the number of the proccess?

Comment: What makes you think you need to do that ?

Comment: The formula is : 1-p^n n=number of proccess, p=-a probability of all processes waiting for I/O simultaneously....Am I right?

Comment: No, I don't think so - if each process had the same probability `p` then that would be correct, but if they each have a different probability, `p0`, `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, then it's `(1 - p0 * p1 * p2 * p3)`, as I explained in the answer above.

Comment: Why do multiplication(not others) for cpu idle? Is there some proof or theory
?

Comment: @Vonfry: it's just basic probability theory - if you have 4 coin tosses then the probability of getting 4 heads is 0.5*0.5*0.5*0.5.

Comment: I have another question : If the waiting time for a process is `p` and there are `n` processes in the memory then the CPU utilization is given by? Intuitively, I thought the answer is `1-p^n`, but the actual answer is `p^n`, how? I still can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: @madhuspot: comments are not intended for additional questions - I suggest you post a new question and include a link to this question for context.

Comment: @PaulR sir, could you glance at the similar question? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55562021/calculation-of-cpu-utilization